# Expand only a single group using groupie library kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, groupie

I Am using groupie expandable recyclerview, I only have to expand current group and also have to collapse previous expanded group, to be precise at a time there should be only one group expanded.. currently I'm using ontoggleExpanded() method how can I achieve above please post an answer

I'm using ontoggleExpanded() method of "groupie" library but I only have to expand one Group at a time
currently it expands all groups what code should I change

Answer (score 0):

A kotlin solution was provided by ValCanBuild in the library's github issues:
https://github.com/lisawray/groupie/issues/301 - The following code is copy-pasted from the issue:

```
class ExpandableHeaderItem : ExpandableItem {

    var onExpandListener: ((ExpandableGroup) -> Unit)? = null

    private lateinit var expandableGroup: ExpandableGroup

    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        super.bind(viewHolder, position)

        // Initial icon state -- not animated.
        viewHolder.icon.apply {
            ...
            setOnClickListener {
                expandableGroup.onToggleExpanded()
                onExpandListener?.invoke(expandableGroup)
                ....
            }
        }

        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

```
val testExpGrpSection = Section().apply {
            val expandableGroups = mutableListOf<ExpandableGroup>()
            for (i in 0..3) {
                val header = ExpandableHeaderItem()
                val group = ExpandableGroup(header)
                // here you would add children to the group
                header.onExpandListener = { toggledGroup ->
                    if (toggledGroup.isExpanded) {
                       // When a group is expanded, collapse all other groups
                        expandableGroups.forEach {
                            if (it != toggledGroup && it.isExpanded) {
                                it.onToggleExpanded()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                expandableGroups.add(group)
                add(group)
            }
        }
```

A java equivalent would be an `interface` listener inside your expandable item header:

```
public interface onExpandedListener {
        void onStateChanged(ExpandableGroup exGroup, int position);
    }

private onExpandedListener listener;

@Override
    public void bind(final ViewItemHeaderBinding viewBinding, int position) {
    viewBinding
        .getRoot()
        .setOnClickListener(
             new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       // must be called in order
                       // onToggleExpanded then onStateChanged
                       expandableGroup.onToggleExpanded();
                       if (listener != null) {
                             listener.onStateChanged(expandableGroup, position);
                       }
                         bindIcon(viewBinding);
                       }
                    });
}
```

Now you need to pass this listener either through the constructor

```
 public ExpandableHeaderItem(Model m, onExpandedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

or add a public setListener method.

```
public void setListener(onExpandedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

Now when you populate the adapter:

```
groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(); expandedGroups = new ArrayList<ExpandableGroup>();
for (Model m : models) {
     // add header models to groups
     expandableHeaderItem = new ExpandableHeaderItem(model);
     ExpandableGroup expandableGroup = new ExpandableGroup(expandableHeaderItem);
            
     // listener when a group is expanded
     expandableHeaderItem.setListener(
                    new ExpandableHeaderItem.onExpandedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStateChanged(ExpandableGroup exGroup, int position) {
                            if (exGroup.isExpanded()) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < expandedGroups.size(); i++) {
                                    if(expandedGroups.get(i) != exGroup && expandedGroups.get(i).isExpanded() ) {
                                       expandedGroups.get(i).onToggleExpanded();
                                    }
                                 }
                            }
                        }
                    });
            //add expandable group to the already expanded groups array
            expandedGroups.add(expandableGroup);
            // add model groups to adapter
            groupAdapter.add(expandableGroup);
    }// end of for loop
        

binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
```